# How do I create a replacement root CA without migrating old certificates?

Tags: migration, certificate-authority, windows-server-2022

Expanding on my post here: [How do I fix missing or multiple CA certificates causing chain issues?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1112521/how-do-i-fix-missing-or-multiple-ca-certificates-causing-chain-issues)

I believe the issue above is that there are missing root CA certs in the CA itself and group policy and I cannot find them in our IT file shares, cert backups, etc.  I think this was caused by a botched root CA migration many years ago by a previous admin.  IMO, the best way to resolve this issue is to replace the root CA with a new one without moving the certs to the new CA.  We'd like to try implementing always on VPN which requires a CA and I don't want to keep using our verification crippled root CA for this.

The CA is used for document signing, WIFI access certificates, code signing, and internal SSL certificates.  There are tens of thousands of certificates over the last 10 years.

One hiccup is half our users are remote and rarely use VPN.  Issues have started coming up where months old policy is still in effect for some of these people and I don't know how changing root CA will affect them.

How can I move our org to a new root CA with minimal issues?

Comment: Do you have any any intermediate ca under that root ca in the hierarchy and is it ad integrated

Comment: There are no intermediate CA roles but if you click the link in my post I believe the root CA is also listed as an intermediate for some reason?  I don't know why the chain is so long for 1 server.

Comment: `One hiccup is half our users are remote and rarely use VPN. Issues... where months old policy is still in effect for some of these people and I don't know how changing root CA will affect them.` this should not be an issue when using even minimum Configuration Management solution to manage and update endpoints. If half the fleet of endpoints has no management capability, that's a different audience/problem/solution. For example, it should be trivial to deploy and manage trusted root certificates by packaging an MSI, like any other updates.

Answer (score 2):

Certs have two parts - the private key and the public key. If you want to issue new certificates you will need a valid and working root CA with private key. However, for existing, non-expired certs issued to endpoints all you need is the root CA public key. Any device that currently trusts those certs will have the public root cert on it. You can export that and import it on any other device you want to trust those certs. However, as mentioned, you will need to rebuild your CA, redeploy a new root cert, and redeploy all existing certificates to move forward with a sustainable environment. All existing certs are either expired or will expire.

Once the root cert expires, all other certs will be invalidated. So, if you do this before that, you should be able to maintain connectivity and get a GPO to push out new root certs, reconfigure VPN, etc. For those systems that have an expired cert - there is nothing you can do. You might want to consider enabling username/password authentication on the VPN (with optional MFA) so that they can connect, refresh their group policy, receive a new cert, and then switch back to always on cert-based VPN authentication.

If you're lucky, perhaps your authentication server has an option to ignore expired certificates and only validate the root CA that signed them. That would be another, optional work around.